# How to use Bootstrap chosen dropdown with dynamically added controls?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-chosen

I am working on a Bootstrap chosen dropdown. When controls and bind as `$selector.chosen()` on page load, it is working fine. But when I add new controls dynamically using JavaScript. Newly added controls are not affected.

How can I solve that problem?

Answer (score 0):

Did you regenerate tags properly?
You should generate all the tags after your event.

```
function makenewlist(result){

var cnt = result.length;
console.log('count: '+cnt);
var selectValues = {};
for(var i=0; i<cnt; i++){
    selectValues[i] = result[i].title;

    console.log(result[i].title);
    console.log('see this?');
}
$('#targetDOM').unbind().empty();
console.log(selectValues);

var target = $('#targetDOM');

$.each(selectValues, function(key, value) {   
    console.log(value);
    var options = $('<option></options>');
    options.append(value);
         .attr("value",key)
         .text(value)); 
    target.append(options);
}); 
}
```

...and try using on() method, and finally check all the methods are inside of $(document).ready().

If you still have the same problem, just let me know.

best regards

Comment: Is there any other way ? Cause if I do this way my code will not be maintainable anymore . There are a lot of very dynamic controls .